# How to resolve JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC?

Tags: java, maven, bouncycastle

I am working on a jar file in java. To work on that I need bouncy castle installed. I will later convert this into java google cloud function so I don't want any dependency with the system. When I try to run my project I am getting the mentioned error.

I have created a java project using maven.
This is command I have used:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=my-function -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

My java function is (MyFunction.java):

```
package com.example; 

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider; 
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastlePQCProvider; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.security.Security; 

public class MyFunction { 
  @Override public void service() throws IOException { 

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()); 
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastlePQCProvider()); 
    try { 
      String path = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\temp.jar"; 
      ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java","-jar",path); 
  
      processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true); 
      Process process = processBuilder.start(); 
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); 
      StringBuilder op = new StringBuilder(); 
      String l; 
      while((l = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
        op.append(l).append("\n"); 
      } 
      int exitCode = process.waitFor(); 
      System.out.println("Output: \n" + op.toString()); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
      System.out.println("Error") 
    } 
  } 
}
```

I am running the project with commands:

```
mvn clean package
mvn function:run
```

Whenever I run it I am getting the below message:

```
JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
```

Pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-function</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

  <name>my-function</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.functions</groupId>
      <artifactId>functions-framework-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15to18 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15to18</artifactId>
      <version>1.72</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <artifactSet>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>org.bouncycastle:*:*:*</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </artifactSet>
          <transformers>
            <transformer
                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <manifestEntries>
                <Main-Class>com.example.Main</Main-Class>
                <Class-Path>. ./lib/bcprov-jdk15to18-1.72.jar</Class-Path>
              </manifestEntries>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
          <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
          <shadedClassifierName>fat</shadedClassifierName>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
     
      <plugin>
          <groupId>com.google.cloud.functions</groupId>
          <artifactId>function-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.10.0</version>
          <configuration>
              <functionTarget>com.example.MyFunction</functionTarget>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Maven version:  Apache maven 3.8.8
Java version: 17.0.2

What am I doing wrong? I have added registered bouncy castle under security provider and also added bouncy castle as a dependency in pom (as an alternate to adding jar file in installed java folder).